# JAX-WS web service - Get portion of input XML in String to a field

Tags: jax-ws, java-ee-5

I have a Java class with a method exposed as a webservice method. Below is my Java class.

```
    @WebService
    public class TestService{

        public String testMethod(InputVO input) {

        }
    }

        public class InputVO{
           private Data data;

        }

        public class Data{
            private String xmlData;
        }
```

Now in my InputVO, I've a Data field which has a String xmlData.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:svc="http://test.svc.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <svc:testMethod>
         <arg0>
             <data>
               <!-- ANY XML CONTENT-->
            </data>
         </arg0>
      </svc:service>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the structure of the Input XML file that my service expects. Inside the data element, I should be able to pass any XML content. Now in my service's `testMethod`, I should get this data in the XML format in `xmlData` element of `Data` object. I've set  for the content inside data in the xsd file of my wsdl.

```
 <xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

But when I check my `xmlData` field in `InputVO`, it is coming as null. How do I set the complete String XML data into `xmlData` field? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether your classes are properly annotated, seems some XML annotation are missing.

Comment: I've giving the @WebService annotation for the web service class. Is there anything more that i need to give?

Comment: besides `@WebService`, please check for XML to Java schema mapping, i.e JAXB bindings like `@XmlRootElement` on your customized input param to web service

Comment: That is internally taken care by the JAX-WS runtime right? Where do I specify this? Could you please provide me some examples/tutorials for this?

Comment: have a look at this example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/

Comment: JAX-WS would do data binding for you but you need to tell JAX-WS  run-time about the data binding. The wsgen commands as specified by the above example is generating the same binding. that will be used by the JAX-WS run-time to convert your incoming XML to java pojo